# Insert using a subquery as a target

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT id,col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM table WHERE col1=1234) 
   VALUES(SEQ.NEXTVAL,2456,'qwew','12312','12312');
```

For the above query, I thought, I can only insert rows to `table` where the `col1` has value of `1234`. But, I was able to insert values other than `1234` for `col1`.

Question:

Why do we need the query like above? What is the real life scenario to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically a construct allowing for updateable Views. For a multi table scenario a INSERT can only be to one of the underlying tables. There has to be a One-One relationship between the View and the table being inserted into.

The query you have shown is a inline view extending the same concept.

Read here for more documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/view-updatability.html

Real life - is so as to be able to do this via View gives flexibility, ease. But more valuable inputs are welcome.

Comment: The link points to the MySQL documentation, NOT the documentation for Oracle RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware you could do that, to be honest, but I suppose it is a by-product of the fact that you can insert into a view, and `(SELECT id,col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM table WHERE col1=1234)` is an in-line view.

As you imply, in the case of an INSERT there isn't much point, but it can be useful for an UPDATE or DELETE, typically where a join is involved:

```
update (select id, col1 from table1
        join   table2 on table2.col2 = table1.col2
        where  table2.col3 = 'X'
       )
set    col1 = 'Y';
```

This will only work if the column is considered updatable by Oracle, which requires that there is a foreign key from table1 to table2 in this example.

With "real" views you can make the restriction on an insert:

```
create view myview as SELECT id,col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM table WHERE col1=1234
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

The `WITH CHECK OPTION` clause means that the WHERE clause of the view must not be violated by the new rows:

```
SQL> insert into myview (id, col1) values (SEQ.NEXTVAL, 9876);
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01402: view WITH CHECK OPTION where-clause violation
```

I don't think there is a way to do that with inline views though.