# Oracle: Insert into select... in the

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the advantage of inserting into a select of a table over simply inserting into the table?

eg

```
insert into
( select COL1
       , COL2
  from   Table1
  where  1=2                  <= this and above is the focus of the question.
) select COL3, COL4 from Table2 ;
```

It seems to do the same thing as:

```
insert into Table1
( COL1, COL2 )
select COL3, COL4 from Table2 ;
```

This is the first time I've seen this; our Sr Dev says there is some advantage but he can't remember what it is.

It may make sense in a way if one was inserting a "select *..." from a table with lots of columns, and we want to be lazy, but... we're not. We're enumerating each column in the table.

Database is Oracle 11gR2, but this query was written probably in 10g or before.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you talking about `INSERT INTO t1(col1, col2, ...) SELECT ...` (well-known), or are you talking about `INSERT INTO(SELECT col1, ... FROM t1` (I've never seen this before)?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: Your 2nd example. I'd not seen it either, and been looking at SQL since '91 and a couple dozen projects.

ie Your: 
INSERT INTO(SELECT col1, ... FROM t1 (I've never seen this before)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert using a subquery as a target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898575/insert-using-a-subquery-as-a-target)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898575/insert-using-a-subquery-as-a-target - closing as duplicate.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt:
Good find. Its more info, but if that's the definitive answer then it doesn't make much sense to use a view-on-the-fly for an INSERT statement.

It references Oracle documentation, but that doc seems to be for mySQL. And, it doesn't seem to apply to Oracle; specifically, that the view has to have all columns of the table. See example below.

In our circumstance, the coder was using all tables in his on-the-fly views. So, I'm still open to a definitive answer.

Comment: I intend to come back and make the coding sections into a block. Until then, please bear with:   

create table abc
( a number 
, b number
, c number
, constraint abc_pk primary key ( a )
) 
;
create or replace view ab
as select A, B from abc
;
insert into 
( select A, B from ab )
( select * from
  ( select NUM_ROWS, max( BLOCKS )
    from   All_Tables
    where  NUM_ROWS is not null
    group by NUM_ROWS
) )
; -- SUCCEEDS
rollback

Comment: <continued>

insert into 
( select A, B from abc )
( select * from
  ( select NUM_ROWS, max( BLOCKS )
    from   All_Tables
    where  NUM_ROWS is not null
    group by NUM_ROWS
) )
; -- SUCCEEDS
rollback
;
truncate table abc 
;
alter table abc
modify C not null
;
insert into 
( select A, B from abc )
( select * from
  ( select NUM_ROWS, max( BLOCKS )
    from   All_Tables
    where  NUM_ROWS is not null
    group by NUM_ROWS
) )
; -- FAILS

Comment: Good point about the link - it indeed points the MySQL documentation (I left a comment pointing this out), whereas the question was indeed about the Oracle RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

> we want to be lazy

No, we use `insert into table(col1, col2) select col2, col2 from ...` when there is a lot of records (for example 1M) and we don't want to create a the `values` section for each. Let's imagine how much time it takes if you write

```
insert into table (col1, col2) 
values (select col1, col2 from (select col1, col2, rownum rn from ...) where rn = 1);
insert into table (col1, col2) 
values (select col1, col2 from (select col1, col2, rownum rn from ...) where rn = 2);
...
insert into table (col1, col2) 
values (select col1, col2 from (select col1, col2, rownum rn from ...) where rn = 1000000);
```

`insert select` is faster way for copying data from one table(several tables) to an another table.

Comment: As far as I understand it, this doesn't answer the question - see the comments by me and the OP.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Thanks for your comment, I might have written it when the question didn't look like it does now.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell. It's a lot easier. Especially when you have a massive query that you dont wanna rebuild,or if you have a crapton of objects, or values you are inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Without WITH CHECK OPTION specified, I don't know of any purpose for this syntax. If you specify WITH CHECK OPTION, you can effectively implement an ad-hoc check constraint within your insert statement.

```
insert into
( select COL1
       , COL2
  from   Table1
  where  1=2 WITH CHECK OPTION
) select COL3, COL4 from Table2 ;
```

The above will never insert a record, because 1 will never equal 2.
The statement below will insert a record as long as COL3 is less than 100, otherwise an exception is raised.

```
insert into
( select COL1
       , COL2
  from   Table1
  where  COL1 < 100 WITH CHECK OPTION
) select COL3, COL4 from Table2 ;
```

Comment: Thanks; no check option. 

It may be someone was trying to be fancy or vengeful.

Comment: sorry for the unformatting; will figure out later how to do a block  for ease of reading.

Comment: Our discussion prompted some questions of my own. It would not have been surprising if an unqualified select in the "into" would have failed if there were rows in the table. It SUCCEEDED. 

SQL> delete from Table1 ;  

8587 rows deleted.  

SQL> insert into 2 ( select COL1 3 , COL2 4 from Table1 5 ) select COL1, COL2 from Table2 ; 2857 rows created. SQL> / 2857 rows created. SQL> / 2857 rows created. SQL> commit ; Commit complete. SQL> select count( * ) from Table1 ; COUNT(*) ---------- 8571 </blink>

Comment: The insert succeeds if the new row would be included in the results of the select statement.